# awk/printf formating number strange behaviour

Tags: bash, awk, printf

The following piece of code is supposed to left pad number in the column 1.

```
input="/home/user_install/folders_LIST_SIZES_MY_FOLDERS.txt"
while IFS= read -r line ; do 
  sudo du  -sm $line | LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF8 awk '{printf "% 11 '\''d  : %s\n",  $1 , $2}'
done < "$input"
```

The expected result should be :

```
    155 283  : /
          0  : /100_samba
        462  : /backup_sys
         62  : /backup_sys_data
          0  : /bdd
          0  : /data
          0  : /data1_pub
          1  : /data3_dwnld_pub
          0  : /data4_mk_dvd_pub
          0  : /data5_my_tmp_pub
      1 211  : /home
          0  : /local
         13  : /root
          0  : /srv
     33 313  : /virtual_0_backup_vdi
     14 689  : /virtual_linux_1
     99 116  : /virtual_win_1
        300  : /win_linux_echange_1
```

The real result is :

```
  155 283  : /
          0  : /100_samba
        462  : /backup_sys
         62  : /backup_sys_data
          0  : /bdd
          0  : /data
          0  : /data1_pub
          1  : /data3_dwnld_pub
          0  : /data4_mk_dvd_pub
          0  : /data5_my_tmp_pub
    1 211  : /home
          0  : /local
         13  : /root
          0  : /srv
   33 313  : /virtual_0_backup_vdi
   14 689  : /virtual_linux_1
   99 116  : /virtual_win_1
        300  : /win_linux_echange_1
```

When a number has more than 3 digits, there is a 1 digit shift to the left.

Comment: Is it better if you pipe output in `column -t` ?

Comment: What is output of `du -ms /home` ?

Comment: Can you help me by showing me with an example How to do  "pipe output in column -t"

Comment: sudo du -ms /home
1222    /home

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you considered `sudo foo | normal_user` environment differences? `sudo -E du ...` can help minimize.

Comment: I actually don't dislike the alignment in the real output as much as in the expected output. Both are horrible but still...

Comment: I'm familiar with the "usual" `printf` format specifiers, like `%s` that you are using. I don't however, understand `"% 11 '\''d` . I'm guessing this is related to your use of  `LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF8` but maybe you can verbally parse the `%<space>11 '\'d` for us? (Preferably, in the body of the question). Tnx and Good luck!

Comment: Out put without sudo :

        462  : /backup_sys

    1 222  : /home

Comment: @shellter looks like a variation on the `%'11d' format that adds 1000's separator, usually a period or comma but a space in this case ... ?

Comment: "%011 '\''d 
"
print number padded with 11 "0" and with a comma as a thousand separator this is standard.

LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF8 replace "," from us_US.UTF8 by a space from "fr_FR.UTF8

So a print result looks like : >>>>00000000462<<<

Or

So a print result looks like : >>>>000 130 462<<<

Comment: pluse-uno for interesting question in the first place, and good follow up on requests for clarifications. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 6):

Using input numbers of `1234567`, `123456` and `123` ...

- if I use `LC_NUMERIC=en_US` everything lines up correctly with a comma as the 1000s delimiter

  ```
  1,234,567 :
    123,456 :
        123 :
  ```
- if I use `LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF8` I get the same shifting as seen in OP's output

  ```
  1 234 567 :
     123 456 :
          123 :
  ```

With the 2nd set of data it's as if the space delimiter is followed by a backspace, or perhaps ... represented by a multi-byte character?

Piping the 2nd set of data to `od -c` I get:

```
0000000   1 302 240   2   3   4 302 240   5   6   7       :  \n
0000020       1   2   3 302 240   4   5   6       :  \n
0000040                   1   2   3       :  \n
0000052
```

So, that 1-byte space delimiter is actually implemented as 2 bytes (`302 240` - one printable character, one non-printable character).

Since the `printf` formatting is based on number of bytes and not number of (printable) characters, each non-printable character 'eats up' one output position thus causing the final output to shift (or shrink) by one (visible/printable) position.

---

One workaround consists of splitting the formatting into 2 separate operations, eg:

```
printf '1234567\n123456\n123\n' |
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF8 awk '{ x = sprintf("%\04711d",$1 )  # format just the number
                             printf "%13s :\n",x          # feed formatted number to basic string format
                           }'
```

This generates:

```
    1 234 567 :
      123 456 :
          123 :
```

**NOTE:** the 2 bytes are still there, ie, piping this latest set of data to `od -c` generates

```
0000000                   1 302 240   2   3   4 302 240   5   6   7
0000020   :  \n                           1   2   3 302 240   4   5   6
0000040       :  \n                                           1   2   3
0000060       :  \n
0000063
```

---

Some caveats:

- if OP expects to deal with 11-digit numbers then the `(s)printf` formats may need to be modified from `11d/13s`
- as highlighted in the comments section (KamilCuk, Ed Morton, me) the actual bytes, and even number of bytes (2-bytes vs 3-bytes), that make up the 'space delimiter' can vary based on the version of `glibc` used to build the `fr_FR.UTF-8` locale; for a 3-byte character this will cause each delimiter to eat/shift the output by 2 (printing) characters; `awk` is designed to work on characters and not bytes so any attempt to dynamically determine the number of bytes that make up the 1000s separator would require an additional effort (eg: making `system()` calls to `wc`; pre-calculating in `bash` and then passing as a `-v awk_var=byte_count` arg to `awk`; `awk -b`)

Comment: `od -c` is your friend! Good luck to all.

Comment: `LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 locale -c thousands_sep | tail -n1 | xxd -p` -> `e280af` -> https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+202F . But `302 240` is `0xc2 0xa0` the good old https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0 , I wonder if that is a difference in database.

Comment: @KamilCuk fwiw, on one of my systems (cygwin, locale 3.4.6) your code snippet generates `c2a00a` (302 240), while on another system (ubuntu 22, locale 2.35) your code generates `e280af0a` (`342 200 257`); same differences apply when I run OP's code on cygwin vs unbuntu ... same locale (`fr_FR.UTF-8`) but different multi-byte 'thousands_sep'

Comment: Yes, glibc version https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/1d7829991112ac32c28bc6e3c4f1695125c1aa44#diff-feddcb52e29584d5d2752df5967dc8f3f628847812c94c364b5c1d4d031261b3L70

Comment: @markp-fuso : just use `match(str, /$/) - 1` in any multi-byte mode and it'll give you the exact byte count of the string. For non-MB locales like `C` or `POSIX`, this matches the output of `length(str)` ::::::: :::::::: ::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::  e.g. `LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 gawk -e 'BEGIN { print match("\342\200\257", /$/)-1 }'` —> `3` …. and this works regardless of whether `str` is locale-compliant string, or just pure binary data

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with `GNU Awk 4.0.2`

Comment: @markp-fuso I don't recall the details but IIRC locales on cygwin aren't fully implemented, I wouldn't trust anything locale-related there.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto re: `match(str,/$/)-1`, very nice! this should come in handy with some (convoluted) code I've got that's dealing with alignment formatting and color codes

Comment: You can tell awk to treat each character as single byte so `length("\342\200\257")` would output `3` just by calling gawk with the [-b option](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options). The `match()` behavior described in your answer sounds like a bug to me rather than a feature because, AFAIK, `match()` should treat characters the same way that every other awk function treats characters.

Comment: @EdMorton `-b` ... even better

Comment: @markp-fuso yeah, unless you can find something documenting that `match()` functionality as deliberate I'd treat it with a large grain of salt as something that might change some day as part of a "fix", especially when the documentation says ["in gawk, length(), substr(), split(), match() and the other string functions (see String-Manipulation Functions) all work in terms of characters in the local character set, and not in terms of bytes."](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bytes-vs_002e-Characters.html)

Comment: @markp-fuso I asked the gawk provider, Arnold, about that `match(mbchar,/$/)` behavior and he said it's a bug which they have a fix for. So, in a future gawk release, when called without `-b` and given a 3-byte char `match(mbchar,/$/)-1` will produce `1` (the number of chars), not `3`  (the number of bytes), just like `length(mbchar)` does so no-one should rely on today's incorrect behavior.

Comment: By the way, setting `LC_ALL=C` or `LC_ALL=POSIX` will also cause gawk to treat each byte as a character, just like using `-b` does - that would hopefully also work with other awk variants that don't have a `-b` option but I don't have access to any others to test that with at the moment.

Comment: @EdMorton in this case the `LC_ALL=C/POSIX` disables the space-as-thousands-separator (and the non-printing character(s) causing this issue) generated by `LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF8` (at least this is the behavior in my cygwin and ubuntu envs)

Comment: @EdMorton : can you talk to Arnold about not altering the `match()` behavior ? The current setup is already correct, since `match(str, /$/)` is asking the index of the null string closest to the end off string. You said those functions "need to work with characters". A zero-length string is a perfectly valid string, but it's not a "character" per se, since there's locale ordinance value you're supposed to be able to map it to. ……..

Comment: @EdMorton : ….. So `match(str, /$/)` should be a locale independent way of obtaining byte-count. This matches output of `gsub(//, "&", str)`. Altering just `match()` creates a disconnect between `gsub()` and `match()`. Returning just last char index is also under the major assumption the input is perfectly conformant to locale settings. Otherwise, if there are extra bytes embedded somewhere in `str`, then what should `match()` return ? To get the last char index today, assuming input is locale-conforming, then `match(str, /.$/)` would give u the same value as `length(str)`, `RLENGTH := 1`

Comment: @EdMorton : the original setup is already ideal because it allows scripts to safety perform data cleansing without needing an external utility that involves resource-expensive `getline` or `system()`. The proposed change complicate matters quite a bit without actually solving much of anything (since `length(str) == match(str, /.$/)` already). I've tested some code that assumes arnold goes ahead with the planned change, and they take quite a bit longer for circumventing the obstacles.

Comment: @EdMorton : with existing setup, one can obtain `gnu-wc` matching cnt, both 4 `UTF-8 chars` and `bytes` 4 a str that's not valid `UTF-8` at all, w/o triggering any errors/warnings ::: `printf '%s' $'abc\357\243\277xyz=\210:' | gwc -lcm; gawk -e 'BEGIN { print split(___ = "abc\357\243\277xyz=\210:", __, /.?/), match(___, /$/) - 1, RSTART, RLENGTH; ___ = 0; for(_ in __) { print _, "\42"(__[_])"\42", ___ += __[_] == "" }  }' | LC_ALL=C  column -t` ::::::::::::: By last row of the `for ( )` loop, `___`  would have a char count matching that of `gnu-wc`. And no linting warnings even with `-L` flag

Comment: @EdMorton : typo earlier :::: *since there's **no** locale ordinance value you're supposed to be able to map it to. ……* :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: null string and null byte shouldn't share the same ordinance value, as illustrated by ::::::::  `gawk -l ordchr -e '{ print _ = "", (_ == chr(ord(_))) }'`:::::::: which prints `0 (false)`. `\0` has an ASCII value of zero. `""` doesn't exist on the ASCII table and thus shouldn't have a value at all.

Answer (score 0):

With a single `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%10s : %s\n", $1, $3}' file
   155 283 : /
         0 : /100_samba
       462 : /backup_sys
        62 : /backup_sys_data
         0 : /bdd
         0 : /data
         0 : /data1_pub
         1 : /data3_dwnld_pub
         0 : /data4_mk_dvd_pub
         0 : /data5_my_tmp_pub
     1 211 : /home
         0 : /local
        13 : /root
         0 : /srv
    33 313 : /virtual_0_backup_vdi
    14 689 : /virtual_linux_1
    99 116 : /virtual_win_1
       300 : /win_linux_echange_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best try. But list is read twice.

#Given list of folders

input="/home/user_install/folders_LIST_SIZES_MY_FOLDERS.txt"

#Temporary file with the size in column 1 and the name in column 2

out1="/home/user_install/folders_LIST_SIZES_MY_FOLDERS.out.1"

#Make file out1

```
    while IFS= read -r line ; do    
   sudo du  -sm $line | awk '{print $1}' >> "$out1" 
done < "$input"
```

#Calculate the max length column size for column 1

PAD_VALUE=$(cat "$out1" | awk  '{for (i=1;i<=1;i++) {len=length($i); if (len>lval[i]) {lval[i]=len; lpos[i]=FNR;}}} END{for (i in lval) printf("%d\n",lval[i])}') ((PAD_VALUE++))

#Print a formated output

```
    while IFS= read -r line ; do    
   sudo du  -sm $line | awk  -v a=$PAD_VALUE '{ for(c = 0; c < a ; c++) s = s" " ; s = s$1 ; print substr(s, 1 + length(s) - a) , $2}' 
done < "$input"
```